# Can we apply TTL functionality on ES version 7.17.6?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-7

Use Case:
Our use case requires Elasticsearch to automatically delete documents older than a specific time period on a regular basis. For instance, if we have 200 documents and 75 of them are older than 2 years, Elasticsearch should automatically delete these 75 documents.

Problem:
Initially, we relied on Elasticsearch's TTL feature to achieve this functionality. However, the TTL feature has been deprecated in Elasticsearch version 7.17.6. We explored the Index Lifecycle Management (ILM) feature, but unfortunately, it doesn't provide the capability to delete specific documents while keeping others intact.

We are looking for a solution that allows Elasticsearch to handle this functionality automatically, without requiring any manual intervention. While the Delete by Query feature is an option, we prefer a more automated approach. Therefore, we are seeking alternative solutions to achieve our requirements.